Socket c++ window
When I create server socket and client socket in the same laptop ,the server console revieve data from client console but the problem is when I copy client socket to deferent laptop the server socket does not receive any data from that client.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Please help me please

Please refrain from using link to images in your questions. There are markdown functionality inside SO for just that; to post code. Please update you question with a minimal, reproducible example.

The problem is that you are using the IP address 127.0.0.1. This will always point to your own device.
To connect to the server, you need to figure out the local IP address of the device where the server is running, and replace 127.0.0.1 with this IP in the client code.
You can find the IP of the server by opening a terminal and typing ipconfig (assuming you are on Windows). The local address is most likely located under IPv4 Address.

How to convert a file to char array for sending by winsock2 ?
